# Parsing/sorting/de-duplicating large matrix of info in UTF-8 form

Tags: utf-8, terminal

I have a large file in UTF-8 form (I've encoded it from iso-8859-1 form) that I have opened in terminal on mac.

I've been trying to use `parse.date` function to convert data in one of the column fields to date form.

I also need to filter all of the rows (each row represents a company, each column represents different data field for each company: i.e. founder, location, year created, etc.) on a certain column field.

As a bonus I would like to de-duplicate the data as well.

Then finally, I'd like to run analysis on this data by sorting the data via different column fields and working with survival curves.

I've been scouring the internet for the appropriate terminal commands to approach this with. Could anyone give me direction on how to get started?

[image: Image of Data Matrix with Headers]
[image: Image of Data Matrix]

Comment: what have you tried so far? this sounds like something that if you researched terminal commands and piping on google wouldn't be too much of an issue.

Comment: I've done quite a bit of searching for terminal commands to begin to parse the data and convert the field "year created" to date using parse.date and haven't found anything helpful. Not terribly experience in terminal command lines so I was hoping for some guidance here.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show us what commands you've used so far, the data you started with (perhaps just 2-3 rows) and what you end up with. I'm thinking you could try using regular expressions with grep and doing a find, alter, and then replace the relevant values.

Comment: I haven't tried any commands yet because I haven't found anything applicable that I've felt able to even try. Sorry for the lack of groundwork I've done, like I said, I'm trying to learn how to work with files this big in the terminal from the ground up right now. Also, I'm new to stack and tried including a screenshot of the data but wasn't able to add images because of my reputation score. 

Any hints as to how to share images of the data?

Only command I've used so far is thisto simply open the file as UTF-8 (file name is DB_ARCHIVE):
$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 DB_ARCHIVE

Comment: Ah! Well if you put the link in the comment I'll edit your question to include it. My advice in terms of the terminal is to break everything down into the smallest possible steps. Also check out the man pages or some bash tutorials.

Comment: Here's the link to the screenshot of the data I tried to upload when asking my question:  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yBJmP.png

Comment: it will take a few min for the edit to be approved... but ive added in the photo

Comment: Thanks, David! Really appreciate your help. If we should move this to chat, let me know. I also am going to try to add a link to the top of the data set with some of the column headers included so that you can see what it looks like up top.

Comment: Here is the link to the image including the column headers at the top of the file:
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Xvy.png

Comment: Hey Jack I'm not sure I can help you answer this question in full past what I've already said. It's not my area of expertise - i dont even know what a survival curve is :)  I'll add in the extra photo.

Comment: btw I've also reworded your question on this edit to help getting people to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

first problem is seperating fields,
i assume fields are TAB-separated;

```
cat file.txt | sort -t$'\t' -k 2
```

If there are TABS and spaces messed up together,
i would assume there is not successive spaces inside a field.
So i would write it this way;

```
cat file.txt |  sed -e 's/\s\+/\t/' | sort -t$'\t' -k 2
```

this will sort the file.txt, according to the 2 column.

- if column 2 is numeric, add **-n** option.
- if you want **stable sort** (which will keep previous ordering whenever possible) add **-s** option.
- if you want to eliminate duplicates add **-u** option.

  ```
  cat file.txt | sort -t$'\t' -k 2 -n -s -u
  ```

for more details;

```
man sort
```

(i don't know about parse.date function.)